# How Can I Take Values from notepad text file to datagrid header ? i only want to take headers not data

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Width="150" Binding="{Binding A}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Width="100" Binding="{Binding B}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="C" Width="100" Binding="{Binding C}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Width="100" Binding="{Binding D}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="E" Width="100" Binding="{Binding E}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="F" Width="100" Binding="{Binding F}"/>
<DataGrid.Columns/>
```

Now I want to take values from text file 1,2,3,4,5,6 in replace of A,B,C,D,E,F. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a text file, you can use StreamReader:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:/yourfile.txt"), 
                                     Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))) 
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';'); // replace ';' by the your separator

        string header1 = values[0];
        string header2 = values[1];
        string header3 = values[2];
        //...

    }
}
```

For DataGrid headers, you must bind each header to a property. You can try this implementation:

*.xaml

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="Layout">
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Layout, Path=DataContext}" Text="{Binding Header1}"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind
*.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    Layout.DataContext = this.DataContext;
}
```

And ViewModel
*.cs

```
private string header1;
public string Header1
{
    get
    {
        return header1;
    }
    set
    {
        this.header1 = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Header1");
    }
}
```

**Edit**
If you are not using MVVM, you can try this approach:

*.cs

```
string Header1 = string.Empty;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:/yourfile.txt"),
                         Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';'); // replace ';' by the your separator

        Header1 = values[0];
        //...
    }
}
grid.Columns[0].Header = Header1;
```

*.xaml

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding A}"/>
<DataGrid.Columns/>
```

Comment: Are you implementing MMVM?

Comment: can you share your xaml and code behind to help you

Comment: Open discussion, if you can

Comment: hey it works but it does not shows retriveddata from database..what t do?